# Is it possible to have a url redirect to another page and keep the original url in the title bar?

Tags: iis, redirect

A marketer in my company has a landing page on our site:  www.importantcompany.com/amazingproduct

They have a vanity url that goes to the landing page:
www.amazingproduct.com

I successfully created the iis redirect rule.  However, the marketer has comeback and would like to keep the redirect rule, but keep the address in the bar www.amazingproduct.com instead of www.importantcompany.com/amazingproduct

I'm assuming that this is not possible.

The only way to make this work is to create a new site in iis and copy the landing page into the new site and set the new site to go to www.amazingproduct.com

Please let me know if my assumption is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is incorrect.

You could write a filter on IIS that looks at the requested URL and notes if "www.amazingproduct.com" is sent in to do a "Server.Transfer" of the request to the subfolder that would be one solution that wouldn't require a new site at all.

[URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) could also be another way to configure a way around this to some degree.